# Purchase / Acquisition / Order difference?

Tags: differences

I'm building a script where I'm using the term **"Orders"** as orders I get from customers, but I try to find the right word for purchases I make - for example, if I buy a service or product for my company.

That purchase is affection the company stock of course.

What would be the right term to use? purchase? acquisition? something else?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think purchase is fine to describe something you purchase...

Comment: 'Purchases' is acceptable. It is a verb as well as a noun.

Answer (score 1):

I've generally seen "order" qualified by another word in systems where there is ambiguity. For example, I worked at a place where the enterprise system included:

- **Sales orders** which were orders placed by customers for us to fulfill to them.
- **Work orders** which were the instructions to our workers on how to create the products that were ordered in the sales orders.
- **Purchase orders** which were orders placed by us to our vendors for our supplies.

The word "order" by itself can mean just about anything, so especially if it may be out of context or seen among other kinds of orders, it's best just to always pair it with another word to describe what kind of order it is.